# Kronecker delta symmetry?

Tags: tensors

This is quite a simple question for the Kronecker delta does $$\delta_{ij}=\delta_{ji}$$ My textbook implies it does but does not actually state it and hence am looking for clarification.

Comment: Well, yes, because $\delta_{ij}=0$ if $i\neq j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple and you are able to prove it on your own.

Write down the definitions on both sides and compare what the result is. Hint: You have to check two different cases.

Comment: I know that if i=j then they are both 1, and if not they are both 0, but this seems too simple!

Comment: So in every possible case ($i=j$ and $i\neq j$) both sides coincide. Therefore equality holds. qed

Answer (score 1):

Note that for general curvilinear coordinates, the property

$$
\delta_{ij} = 0, \: i \neq j \quad \delta_{ij}= 1, \: i=j
$$

even if true in one basis, is NOT true in general, because $\delta_{ij}$ transforms as a (0,2) tensor. However, the (mixed) (1,1) Kronecker delta $\delta^i_j$ does have this property.